# How do I upgrade my app signing key again when I have already done it once this year?

Tags: google-play, google-play-console, google-developers-console

I want to release a new version of my app. But everytime I try to upload my **aab** file, I keep getting this error:

```
Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your App Bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again. Your App Bundle is expected to be signed with the certificate with fingerprint:

SHA1: DA:A0:FD:48:39:4C:3D:32:F8:2C:F0:92:80:22:12:FE:C3:8E:87:C0

but the certificate used to sign the App Bundle you uploaded has fingerprint:

SHA1: D0:3A:E7:13:8C:F5:5C:E9:A9:5F:A6:DA:5B:A3:71:57:7B:29:DA:CD
```

To change my SHA1 key, I tried to request key upgrade in my **Play Console** . But the option is greyed out and shows this message

```
Your signing key has been upgraded in the past year. This can be done once annually.
```

What do I do now? How do I upload my updated app in play store?